# Webview2.h not found with MSVC on Github Actions

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake, webview

Disclaimer: I am a Linux user, thus my knowledge and ability to debug are limited.

I am using https://github.com/webview/webview to provide a webview frontend to my CMake project.

```yaml
      - name: Install Linux Dependencies
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install ninja-build libgtk-3-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev xxd
      
      - name: Install Windows Dependencies
        if: runner.os == 'Windows'
        run: |
          choco install ninja xxd webview2-runtime
```

```
    if(APPLE)
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "-framework WebKit")
    elseif (UNIX)
        find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
        pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
        pkg_check_modules(WEBKIT2GTK4 REQUIRED webkit2gtk-4.0)
        include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${WEBKIT2GTK4_INCLUDE_DIRS})
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GTK3_LIBRARIES} ${WEBKIT2GTK4_LIBRARIES})
    elseif (MSVC)
        target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -mwindows -Ilibs/webview2/build/native/include -ladvapi32 -lole32 -lshell32 -lshlwapi -luser32 -lversion)
    endif()
```

Whilst the project compiles just fine on MacOS and Linux, on Windows it fails with the following error:

```
fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'WebView2.h': No such file or directory
```

I did install webview2-runtime using chocolatey on a Windows 10 install. I saw someone online suggest the following command
`echo "WEBVIEW2_INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView2\include" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

but that path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView2`) didn't exist after installing.

I tried looking at the official example by Microsoft, but it was using msbuild and nugget, which I'd avoid unless there is no other solution.

Here is a link to the project, if it helps: https://github.com/badea-codrut-cti/proiect-poo/